# Wordpress update leads to 404 error on admin page and signup. CSS mishap with all plugin related functions

Tags: images, css, links, updates

I have recently updated **WordPress** live website in production. After the update I am facing the following problems.

- wp-admin link is not working: it throws a 404 error page.
  Ref: http://bubblz.in/login-page/
- CSS of existing plugins messed up. 
  Ref: http://bubblz.in/wedding-events

Comment: there is no question here :(. You should just revert to your backup and work on all the issues on a development server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all never update production/live version, download it and try it locally or on dev server.

**http://bubblz.in/wp-admin** seems working for me. Check do you have still page named login-page.

For conflict css files you will need to remove them.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_remove_theme_enqueues', 11 );

function wp_remove_theme_enqueues()
{
    if( is_ThatPage()//search for that page ) 
    {
        wp_dequeue_script('cssFile');
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Fine, figuring out the css problem and mainly in header of all product listings